# Registration using data from external sources

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, registration

I just recently picked up Laravel. I am trying to change `Registrar.php` to suit my needs in Laravel 5.

The registration flow is as follows:

1. Ask user for username and password
2. Use these details to make request to an external service (may take around 20s)
3. Check if the details supplied are correct, if they aren't throw an error
4. Retrieve information from an external service and create the account

I cannot make the account in one step, I need to make fetch information from the service first.

- Does Laravel have a facade to make cURL requests?
- How do I throw custom errors?
- Can I create a user and then add information later on? How?

---

In vanilla PHP I would have made an AJAX call that initiates the request and allows the user to continue and login after the AJAX call returned data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

- For the cURL requests I suggest using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) (Laravel dosn't have a special Facade or Service Provider for that).
- For handling errors with Laravel check the [Errors Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors).
- For handling the user create/update, Laravel already ships with a User Eloquent Model, which you can use to create and update the account, which would look something along these lines:

```php
// Create the new user
$user = User::create([ /* array with details goes here */ ]);

// Do your other stuff...

// Update the user's other details
$user->detail = "Some detail"; // add as many columns as you like
$user->save();
```

Any aditional details on working with models you can find in the [Eloquent Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent).